# Use MySql in ABP vnext framework

Tags: abp

I want to use MySQL with ABP vnext. I spend many hours to find solution but i found nothing. I read documents and google the issue but did not find any solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I advise you read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article as it provides very useful information for newcomers on how to write questions. Quality questions help us provide you quality answers - Can you provide your attempt at solving the issue?

Comment: I am waiting as well, though until either Oracle's MySql .NET connector or Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql supports EF Core 3.0 there isn't much ABP can do to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL by using [Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL/) package.

1. In your **.EntityFrameworkCore** project, replace
   `Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` (considering you have
   created a default project) nuget package with
   `Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL`.
2. Replace module
   dependencies in **YourProjectNameEntityFrameworkCoreModule** from
   `typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkCoreSqlServerModule)` to
   `typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkCoreMySQLModule)` with also replacing namespaces (`using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;` to `using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL;`)
3. In your **.EntityFrameworkCore** project, replace `UseSqlServer()` with `UseMySql()` in **YourProjectNameEntityFrameworkCoreModule.cs** file.

Here is [official docs about switching to MySQL Provider](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core-MySQL#switch-to-ef-core-mysql-provider).

You can also check [switching to an other dbms docs](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Entity-Framework-Core-Other-DBMS#switch-to-another-dbms-for-entity-framework-core) for other dbms supports.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to wait for Oracle's MySql .NET connector or Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql to work with EF Core 3.0.  As of this posting (30-Sept-2019), neither does....

[Oracle's EF Core Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html)

[Pomelo NuGet Page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)